# Prestashop core development auto generate xml after order complete

Tags: php, prestashop

Where are Prestashop core functions(methods) that executes order and saving it to db?i wanna re-write core (Order.php) to auto generating XML of each completed order without creating module and hooks in there.

Comment: Maybe you must override order.php or OrderController.php but not modify this files directly

Comment: i wanted to do that,but i didn't understand which method executes and which not.I was rewriting getUniqReferenceOf,so when prestashop calls getUniqReference,should be generated xml or whatever anything i want,but it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mh, I think, that you should ovveride class -> PaymentModule.php -> validateOrder function. Its a step where order validated and sending email to customer, so you could create here XML and send to your mail or save to ftp.